# Python file object encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

*All I say is in the scope of Python2*

As I know, I can get a file object using the builtin `open` function. And a file object has a attribute named as `encoding` used to output Unicode strings.

Now I want to write to a file with a default encoding type(not ASCII), I use the `encoding` but it is readonly, maybe it is reasonable.

Then I tried `codecs` `getwriter` wrapper(I have a file object already), but it seems like it will encoding anything wether it is `Unicode` type or not. As I know , file object will check the content type and file encoding both when do write.

Then I checked the python src code, the file object type provides a method `PyFile_SetEncoding` to set encoding, but only used in `sys` module for `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

Is there a proper way to let file object encode the content to write with a default encoding type if it is `Unicode` type?

And I doubt that why `PyFile_SetEncoding` is provided, but not applied on normal files? It seems like the default encoding type can be known from the file itself if it is not empty, or tell what encoding type I want to write to a new file with at least. Is there a module implementing it?

Or if I'am wrong, please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Can you change how the file is opened? It sounds like you should be using [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead of the `open` from the builtin namespace.

Comment: As I say, codecs stream writer will encoding anything before write. What I do now is custom a wrapper

Comment: What do you even mean by that? Are you trying to write Unicode strings and byte strings through the same file object, without calling `encode` or `decode`? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: However, file write is implemented like this in Python2, it will do encoding according to the file.encoding attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I write a [module](https://github.com/yittg/btef) myself that support passing `encoding` param to `open`, or `set_encoding` for a existed file object.